# Is there a \die command?

Tags: macros, errors, warnings

Is there a command that generates the error or warning of my choice? I'm planning to put it in an `\ifthenelse`, so it can't be a syntax error.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There are commands `\GenericInfo`, `\GenericWarning` and `\GenericError`. For class and package writers there are also `\Class…` and `\Package…` equivalents, described in the [`clsguide`](http://ctan.org/pkg/clsguide).

An example:

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\GenericWarning{}{A simple warning}

\GenericError{(cont.)\space\space}
  {This is a\MessageBreak
    multi-line error\MessageBreak
    message}
  {Describe here where to go for more information}
  {This is the error help (type H to see me)}

\begin{document}
\end{document}
```